# php exec java send to ttyUSB0

Tags: java, php, rxtx

I need to run a java jar that create connection to a device ttyUSB0, through php

The jar file work correctly if I run it from shell with this command

```
java -jar rxtx.jar 'param_to_send'
```

with parameter send to device and "ok" output result

Now I must execute this from php and after several trials, I get this command that seems works correctly

```
$output = param_to_send;
exec("/usr/bin/java -jar rxtx.jar '".$output."' 2>&1" , $output);
```

the output will return "ok", but on my device no connection...

Tried also with shell_exec and exec with sudo/root privileges, but same result...